# How to get a json result/response at View

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have been trying to get a response from my controller to my view, but all I get is plain JSOn display ( Firefox: image attached ) or prompt for json file download. I have tried many approaches. Will someone please show me or give me the code so that I can atleast get a Success at view and can show an alert at least[image].

```
 public JsonResult GetGata()
    {
        List<ProdVM > pvl = new List<ProdVM>();
        try
        { 
            ProdVM pvm1 = new ProdVM();
            pvm1.ProductID = 1;
            pvm1.ProductName = "Computer";
            pvl.Add(pvm1);
            return Json(pvl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myGrid').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Home/GetGata/",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
        { "data": "ProductName" },
        { "data": "ProductID" }
        ]
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datatable plugin expects the ajax endpoint to return data in this format

```
{"data":[["1","Computer"],["2","Camera"]]}
```

You can see that, each item is an array (a string array where each string item is the property value)

This should work

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    var items = new List<string[]>
    {
        new string[] {"1", "Computer"},
        new string[] {"2", "Camera"}
    };
    return Json(new { data = items }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This should work assuming you have a table like this in your page

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

and the js code to call the endpoint to get data and use for the datatable

```
$(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "@Url.Action("GetData")"
    } );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I still get same error like the page. The firefox shows just json value and IE prompts for JSon download. Please someone help me. I am stuck here and cannot practice or learn anything regarding json response coming from .net controller and I get the response at Success and display at html. Please some one see this situation and please help me.

Comment: When you run the page, you arre getting a warning ? If you try to access the end point directly, you might get the error based on the browser setting may be. Try to access the endpoint with something like postman/fiddler/advanced rest client chrome plugin

Comment: I can get Json result at Postman. But I need to get it at .cshtml ( view file).I am accessing the url through localhost. And it need to work on development mode for me to try out all samples for learning purpose. Will you please give me a Hello world type example that you can see at your Visual Studio's localhost, where reponse comes from JsonResult return type from controller and your jquer's success can catch it at alert please???

Comment: Did you try the code i posted above as it is ? It should work when you render that view. What trouble are you having with that ?

Comment: Yes, I tried the above code of yours and see the same problem: plain json result at firefox and at IE there is prompt for download

Comment: Thank you so much for the fiddle .net code. I again copy and pasted, but at Firefix and Chrome, I only see the json data string. And at IE, I get json download prompt. I am using Visual Studio 2015. I am running the app from Visual Studio's local host. Do you think it may be configuration issue? Can you make this work at your personal computer's Visual Studio's localhost? Please  answer. See I am doing everything right, but for some reason, data is not getting rendered with html and css. Please see this situation. I still get json data on browser.

Comment: yes. I copied the code from a sample project in my local computer and pasted in the fiddle.

Comment: What is my Visual Studio's problem? Is it a setting situation at browser or VS? Should I download Visual Studio 2017? I am using VS 2015 on Windows 10. Please think about my this problem. I have done lots of research and it seems that others are having this problem, but I am not quite sure when I use the solution that fixed their problem, why I get json download prompt. What I should do now? It is nice that this problem does not happen for me but it is happening for me. Please advice.

Comment: To start with, why are you worried about what is your browser setting. You are not going to access the endpoint directly on the browser, but will be called from some js code (the one initializing the DataTable) which makes an ajax call. When you call the server from your client side code what is happening ? Are you getting a 200 response (check your browser network tab)

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help. Please note that I am getting 200 status code at localhost: 57116. I wish that I could show you my laptop. But I will be waiting here for resolution.

Comment: if you are getting 200, It will render the datatable correctly (if you are using the code i have in the question) . What is the problem you are facing then ?

Comment: Nothing gets rendered. At firefox, I get json output ( like the picture at top that I posted ) and at IE, I get json file download prompt.

Comment: Will it possible for you to get inside my computer being remote?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for trying to help so patiently. I understand my mistake.
I should have called the method that gives Json response from a view. For example, from Index view, I will call a method that gives a json response.
My problem has been fixed. Thank you again for helping out.